# Break if statement inside infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

This may be an elementary question, but it is breaking my brain.

I have a structure like this in NodeJS (typescript):

```
while(true) {
   if (something) {
      code...
      try{
         dangerousCode();
      }catch(e){
         console.log(e);
         //Now I want to exit from this if statement and go to the next one
      }
      some other code...
   }
   if (somethingElse) ...
}
```

How can I leave a `catch` statement like that and go to the next `if` (so I need to currently leave the `if` statement where the `catch` block is). Should I use `break` or `continue` keyword? Should I do something else?

Comment: So you say that `continue` will leave `catch` and `if` statements? I'll give it a try.

Comment: if has nothing to do with arguments found in a try catch / while  block. i.e. break, continue

Comment: `break` will bring you out of the loop and using `continue`, you will again start from starting from the loop. So both won't work.

Comment: yeah, simply dont do anything in your catch

Comment: @CharchitKapoor That's why my brain is damaging. Would you suggest something?

Answer (score 4):

try something like this

```js
while(true) {
   if (something) {
      code...
      try{
         dangerousCode();
         some other code...
      }catch(e){
         console.log(e);
         // Now you will exit this if block, as there are no more instructions
      }
   }
   if (somethingElse) ...
}
```

If an exception is thrown, it will get caught and handled in the `catch` block and then directly go the next `if` statement.

If no exception occurs, the `dangerousCode()` will execute normally and pass to `some other code...` after it.

Comment: This is a good solution for sure, I thought about it today, I just wanted to see if there was something else to let the rest of code out of my catch block (and maybe put another try catch with a different code). It seems I need to catch the entire block starting from the dangerous code. Thanks for the confirm.

Comment: Good approach. I vote. However, the disadvantage is that a lot of code is put into a try block, which should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add another variable and a condition in this case.

```
let enterFirstIfBlock = true;

while(true) {
   if (enterFirstIfBlock && something) {
      code...
      try{
         dangerousCode();
      } catch(e) {
         console.log(e);
         enterFirstIfBlock = false;
      }
      if (enterFirstIfBlock) {
        some other code...
      }
   }
   if (somethingElse) ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true) {
   if (something) {
      code...
      try{
         dangerousCode();
      }catch(e){
         console.log(e);
         //Now I want to exit from this if statement and go to the next one
      }
      some other code...
   }
   if (somethingElse) ...
}
```

I suggest you move your second if statement to a function say `doSomething()`, and then call this function within your `catch` block, and after first `if`, like this:

```
while(true) {
       if (something) {
          code...
          try{
             dangerousCode();
          }catch(e){
             console.log(e);
             doSomething();
            continue;
             //Now I want to exit from this if statement and go to the next one
          }
          some other code...
       }
       doSomething();
    }
    function doSomething() {
       if (somethingElse) ...
    }
```

You will need to pass appropriate params, and handle them accordingly, and also add continue in after `doSomething` in `catch` if nothing else is required.

Answer (score 0):

An esoteric, but occasionally convenient feature is using a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) with a block scope.

> ### label
>
> The labeled statement can be used with [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) or [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) statements. It is prefixing a statement with an identifier which you can refer to.

It allows you to `break` out of a code block by its label name and continue execution after the end of the block. Here's a contrived example to demonstrate how to use it. (Of course, see the linked documentation as well.)

```js
function fork () {
  return Math.random() < 0.5;
}

function getValue () {
  const useFirst = fork();
  if (fork()) return useFirst ? 'a' : 'b';
  return useFirst ? 1 : 2;
}

while (true) {
  let value = getValue();

  stringCheck:
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
     // code...
     try{
        if (fork()) throw new Error('Bad luck');
     }
     catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
        break stringCheck; // Breaks out of the block associated with the label
     }
     // some other code...
  }

  value = getValue();

  numberCheck:
  if (typeof value === 'number') {
    console.log('Got a number');
    // break numberCheck; // If uncommented, would break out of this block
    break; // Break out of the while loop
  }
}
```